# Is it naughty to have a large utility file?

Tags: organization, code-organization

In my C project I have quite a large utils.c file. It is really full of many utilities of different sorts. I feel a bit naughty just stuffing different miscellaneous functions in there. For example it has some utilities related to low level stuff such as a lowercase() function, and it also has some quite sophisticated utilities such as converting to/from different colour formats.

My question is, is it very naughty to have such a large utils.c with many different types of utilities in it? Should I break it up into many different kinds of utility files? Such as graphics_utils.c and so on What do you think?

Comment: Domenic, i have a feeling the answers to this post (which all seem to be saying the same thing) are 'subjective' in the same sense a design pattern is 'subjective' ;) In other words the 'subjective' tag is inappropriate :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just you that will EVER maintain the stuff, it's a matter of when the complexity gets to the point where you find yourself searching for things.  That would be the time to refactor and reorganize (there's a cost to reorganize, just as there's a cost to not reorganize).

If it's POSSIBLE that anyone else will maintain a project that includes your utils, you have to consider THEIR pain point when deciding when to reorganize.  Theirs is MUCH lower than yours.

Answer (score 9):

Breaking them up into separate files based on categories (ie graphics, strings, etc.) will lead to better organization, making it easier to locate certain pieces of code, having smaller files to go through, instead of just one large file.

Answer (score 7):

You want to break it up, not just for organizational reasons, but because you will have many other files that depend on this one. Because everything will depend on this file, it makes this one file difficult to change because it might cause widespread breakage.

http://ifacethoughts.net/2006/04/15/stable-dependencies-principle/

Comment: it might also make build time less optimal since everything that links to this file will need to be recompiled if it changes.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to break them up into various sub-utils as you say (graphics_utils) when it becomes appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Break it up.  Stuff will be easier to find, easier to reuse, easier to refactor, easier to unit test.  I recently needed to get a set of ISO-8601 date handling methods out of a ginormous Java utility class of static methods, and it was really hard to find the 5% of the code I needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not kosher, because the next guy coming through your code won't know where to look for anything.  Break it up by function, and your coworkers will thank you!

Comment: Sure he will.  It'll be in the giant utils file!

Answer (score 2):

Another advantage that comes from breaking up the file into separates is that when you place it under source control, you can have finer grained control. This really is useful if you have bits that are tweaked/extended/specialised frequently, and other bits that are relatively stable.

Answer (score 2):

Another point: You should organize your code, i. e. break it up in smaller modules and categorize it, because at some point in time you will end up writing a second and third function for the same thing, simply for the reason that you wont find that function that you knew it was there, but you don't remember it's name.

I've got a (rather large) project with such a module and there is programming logic for which there are up to 5-6 implementations (for the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else I would break them up. But I tend to use Extension Methods now, so I would have one class (and one file) per class being extended (e.g. `StringExtensions`, `SqlDataReaderExtensions`, etc). I find this tends to break up the utility methods nicely.